# Add in a blank line every Nth group of data in a single ascii file

Tags: python, arrays, ascii

How do I to add in a blank line after each "jump" from 0 to 1, 1 to 2. 
Here are my code.

```
A =  [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]

with open ("vv.txt" ,"w") as out_file:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in  range(4):
                out_string = str(i) + " " + str(j) + " " +  str(A[i]) + " "
                out_string += "\n"
                out_file.write(out_string)
    out_file.close()
```

Output:

```
    0 0 11 
    0 1 11 
    0 2 11 
    0 3 11 
(add a blank line here)
    1 0 22 
    1 1 22 
    1 2 22 
    1 3 22 
(add a blank line here)
    2 0 33 
    2 1 33 
    2 2 33 
    2 3 33
```

Comment: Two questions really.... how to write a blank line, well, `out_file.write('\n')` will write a new line. Then, you can add a new line wherever you want according to your logic, in your case, each time the inner for loop is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add line break after nested loop:

```
A =  [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]

with open ("vv.txt" ,"w") as out_file:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in  range(4):
                out_string = str(i) + " " + str(j) + " " +  str(A[i]) + " "
                out_string += "\n"
                out_file.write(out_string)
        out_file.write("\n")
    out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a blank line in between your outer loop.
If you don't want a blank line at the very end (as in your example output) you would also need an if statement.

```
A =  [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]

with open ("vv.txt" ,"w") as out_file:
    for i in range(3):
        for j in  range(4):
                out_string = str(i) + " " + str(j) + " " +  str(A[i]) + " "
                out_string += "\n"
                out_file.write(out_string)
        if i < 2:
                out_file.write("\n")
    out_file.close()
```

Remember that `range(3)` gives you `0,1,2` and you only want a newline at `0` and `1` that's why `i < 2` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The much awaited one-liner

```
print('\n\n'.join('\n'.join('%r %r %r'%(i, j, A[i]) for j in range(4)) for i in range(3)),
      file=open("vv.txt", "w")))
```

1. The code above does not add a blank line at the end of file (i.e., the file does not end with `"\n\n"`)
2. The [`.join` method of strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is incredibly useful (and can lead to incredible abuses).
3. Using `print(..., file=...)` in place of `fileobject.write(...)` automatically does the right thing wrt adding a newline at the end of the file.
4. The file object is automatically closed and garbage collected when `print` has finished their job.